# Sometimes X-XSRF is missing from axios request - Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Laravel / Vue / Axios

Sometimes once making requests with axios the X-XSRF-Token is missing which is obviously leading to the request getting blocked by the CSRF middleware. This happens maybe like 2/10 times. All the forms on the page (except login) uses pure axios calls and i have therefor not implemented any logic for setting the token as according to the laravel docs this should be handle automatically when using axios, and again it works, most of the time. My idea is to manually implement the X-CSRF-TOKEN in bootstrap.js however im unsure if this would conflict with the automatic X-XSRF. There does not seem to be any pattern in it being browser or device specific. Also, i have not experienced it myself but my bugsnag tells me it is a problem and every time the X-XSRF header is missing.

All ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Laravel: 8.34 Vue: 2.6.12 Axios: 0.21

Comment: happening in all browsers ?

Comment: @AqibJaved Yes as mentioned there does not seem to be any pattern in browser or device.

Comment: Is there any pattern with regards to timing? Or is it like you do 10 posts directly after login and actually 2 out of 10 fail? Or maybe they start failing after some minutes?

Comment: @Frnak No pattern in regards of timing. My 2/10 is just best guess on how often it happens. I had not been able to make it happen on any of my devices but i can see that it does happen in bugsnag.

Comment: Well... I guess there is some pattern, you just need to find it :) without you sharing your code, it will be hard for us to guess it... maybe you overwrite something in an axios call, maybe you do a call before the token was set, maybe it needs to refresh from time to time or you invalidate it somehow in your backend. We need to see your actualy - relevant - code lines in order to help you in more detail.